# Why won't my furnace run on the generator?

Tags: electrical

I have a portable generator for my standby power connected to a sub panel through a manual transfer switch supplied by a breaker in the main panel. I have separated the neutral and the ground at the sub panel and the transfer switch--they are only bound at the main panel. The problem I'm having is the furnace will not operate on the generator but works fine on normal power.

The furnace model is a GOODMAN GMVC950905DXAB. The generator is a GENERAC XG8000. The thermostat is a Honeywell RTH5160 which uses batter power and only one 15AMP circuit to the furnace, which measures 115.7 volts.

There is a circuit board on the furnace with a 2 digit readout on it that puts out an 88 code that has no definition on the troubleshooting area, but there are two LEDs at the top of the circuit board. One is marked RX and the other is marked status. The RX blinks on generator power but not on normal power. The status LED blinks ounce and then goes out. Normal operation then OP comes on in the readout and the furnace starts to run.

Comment: The make and model of the generator and furnace would help us better answer your question. Some generators put out "dirty" power that control boards don't like.  Some put out a "modified sine wave" which has a stair step pattern on a scope.

Comment: Some additional information about your generator and how you are connecting to your home's power would be very helpful.

Comment: Welcome! Please clarify what "will not operate" means. That gas won't light and remain lit? The blower motors don't come on? Power-on LED indicator on the control board never even lights up? Etc.

Comment: yes 115.7 volts enough to operate the furnace  I'm new at this site so I'm not sure if I'm to answer a question its a goodman furnace if that's any help

Comment: Unless you have a 15kw generator or larger I would expect some circuits to be turned off. Some thermostats cannot function without power is your furnace transformer powered up or on batteries? The transformer may be on a totally separate circuit I have found this to be the case a few times and turn the other circuit on or move the transformer to a different circuit.

Comment: The manual for your furnace indicates a difference for RX blinking between steady flash and rapid flashing. What kind of flashing are you seeing on each type of power? Do you also have A/C? If so, can you turn off the A/C breaker and see if your furnace works on "normal power"?

Comment: the RX flashes steady and yes I have AC and the breaker is off and the furnace still runs on normal power

Comment: In the regular panel turn off every breaker **except** the one for the furnace (and the main breaker). See if the furnace works. If it does, then "not working on generator" may have something to do with quality of power (waveform) or maybe a grounding/neutral issue. But if it does **not** work, then start turning on breakers one at a time until it does work, and then you'll know what other circuits need to be on the generator to get the furnace to work.

Comment: @steve -- what make and model is your transfer switch?

Comment: @steve: every single clarification you have posted here in the comments, you should instead use [the edit link below your post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/213765/edit) to improve the question itself, with those clarifications and any others.

Comment: It sounds like your furnace has some control or safety device that is wrongly powered by a circuit that is not on your generator sub panel.   Eg flue damper, over pressure, zone valve, etc   Normally everything is powered from one circuit after the main boiler cutoff switch.  Look for a part that isn't.

Comment: https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3.supplyhouse.com/manuals/1300979322123/51543_PROD_FILE.pdf. There is your manual.  Look at pages 42 to 48.   Possibly your A/C needs to be powered for your furnace controller to work.  I may be wrong.  Not powered in full operation, just power available to the control circuitry.

Answer (score 1):

Your generator may have a "floating neutral", which the furnace doesn't like. You can see how to solve the problem at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1996Yj8RN04 . You can buy such a plug or make one. A single wire inside the plug connects the ground to the neutral pin (the wide one). Plug it into the unused 110 volt socket on your generator.

Answer (score -2):

Your portable generator has ratings for starting watts and running watts. When you first turn it on, it starts with a higher number of watts then reduces to the amount of running watts. I am wondering if there is a mismatch in watts needed by the furnace and those provided by the generator. Make and model might help us discern this. 8000 watts might just be the starting level, while the generator provides only 5000 (arbitrary number) watts as running watts, underpowering the furnace.

Comment: I seriously doubt that they're underpowering the furnace to that degree -- normally, you'd see voltage and frequency sag in that situation

Comment: That's not what starting/running watts ratings on a generator mean: "running" is the rating for the amount of current that can be continuously drawn from the generator. "Starting" is the amount of current that can be provided for a short time, the absolute maximum the generator can produce, for a short time. This matches the language used on electric motors, which give "starting" and "running" current draws.